# Showing surjectivity of a certain function

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $X=\Bbb R/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation that $y-x = 2n\pi$. Consider the function: $f: X \rightarrow S^1$ ; $f(x) = (\cos (x), \sin (x))$.  Show that this function is surjective.

So I am drawing a blank. I know what it means to be surjective, but showing it for this case is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: If $x \in X$, then $x$ is an equivalence class, not a number. So the notation $f(x) = (\cos(x), \sin(x))$ isn't quite valid unless you define what it means to take the cosine and sine of an equivalence class. Probably you should write something like $f([x]) = (\cos(x), \sin(x))$, where $[x]$ is the equivalence class containing the real number $x$. The first thing you should do is to show that $f$ is well-defined.

Comment: The way this question is phrased makes me feel inclined to look into how much of the question the poster understands and then to help with that before going on to actually answering it. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I don't see how this pertains to topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map
$$
g\colon\mathbb{R}\to S^1
$$
defined by $g(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$. This map is clearly surjective.

### Interlude

Let $\alpha\colon A\to B$ be a map, where $A$ and $B$ are sets. Setting, for $x,y\in A$, $x\sim_\alpha y$ if and only if $\alpha(x)=\alpha(y)$ defines an equivalence relation on $A$. If $\pi\colon A\to A/{\sim_\alpha}$ is the canonical projection $\pi(x)=[x]$ (the equivalence class of $x$), then there exists a unique map $\tilde\alpha\colon A/{\sim_\alpha}\to B$ such that
$$
\alpha=\tilde\alpha\circ\pi
$$
The definition of $\tilde\alpha$ is the only possible one: $\tilde\alpha([x])=\alpha(x)$ and this does not depend on the representative of the equivalence class: if $[x]=[y]$, then $x\sim y$ and so $\alpha(x)=\alpha(y)$.

It is clear that the image of $\alpha$ is the same as the image of $\tilde\alpha$; in particular, $\tilde\alpha$ is surjective if and only if $\alpha$ is surjective.

### End of the argument

In the case of $g$, the equivalence relation is $x\sim y$ if and only if
$$
(\cos x,\sin x)=(\cos y,\sin y)
$$
that is, $x-y$ is an integral multiple of $2\pi$. So the relation $\sim_g$ is exactly the relation you are given and $f=\tilde g$. So $f$ is surjective.

---

Note that if $x\in X$, then $x=[r]$ for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and setting $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$ is not really possible, because $x$ is not a real number. The above arguments fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This function will be bijective, to see this you make the definition of $S^1$ 
$$
S^1=\{(x,y)/ x^2+y^2=1\}=\{(\cos(t),\sin(t)), t\in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
So for every $(x,y)\in S^1 $ it exist $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$
and we know that the application $\pi: R \to X$ is surjective (canonical one) so your function will be surjective as composition of two surjective application.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z \in S_1$ then it exists an angle $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ such that $Z=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))=f(\theta).$ Now, take $x=\theta+2n\pi$ we have $x \in X$ since $x-\theta=2n\pi$ and $f(x)=f(\theta+2n\pi)=f(\theta) =Z.$
This implies that $f$ is surjective.